# Replace a string with a string in BeautifulSoup

Tags: css, class, replace, find, beautifulsoup

I have this class `class = "good"`. I need to replace it with a string, something like `style="word-wrap: break-word" width="400px"`. The entire string `class = "good"` with the string `style="word-wrap: break-word" width="400px"`. With my experimentation `find_all` and `replace_with` don't allow me the required functionality. Is there anyway that could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

find and replace is not needed here as you need to change the attributes of this element instead of any data or html.

Use this

```
$('.good').css('word-wrap', 'break-word').attr('width','400px').removeAttr('class');
```